# Unable to use Remote Desktop to connect to Windows 10 virtual machine on macOS host

Tags: macos, network, windows, remote-desktop, virtualbox

I am using a MacBook Pro with macOS 10.14.5 and VirtualBox 6.0 (with Extension Packs) to create a Windows 10 virtual machine (downloaded from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/).

It runs fine locally, accesses the Internet, but I want to connect to the VM from another Mac or iPad using Microsoft Remote Desktop apps.

To achieve this:

- In VirtualBox configurations for that VM, I have enabled server (remote display) on port 3389, null authentication method.
- In Windows 10 in the VM, I have enabled "Allow remote access to this computer", without requiring network level authentication.
- In Remote Desktop app, I have pointed to the host IP and the specified port (e.g. 192.X.X.X:3389, following instructions on https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html).

Unfortunately, it does not connect. I have tried to ping 192.X.X.X:3389 from the host MacBook and from another Mac, but got "Unkown host". Pinging only the host MacBook IP, without the port, from the other Mac gets a normal response.

I imagine that I need to configure something else to allow access to the VM in macOS.

Can someone advise what I might be missing here, or what else I can try?